# Clearing out a c# form text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a simple hangman style game in a C# form. I have it set as textBox1_TextChanged. Except everytime the user backspaces their guess letter it takes in blank space. How can I make it so after the message saying right/wrong it clears the space. I am getting annoyed at it telling the user they made a wrong guess after they backspace. This is my first post on this forum so sorry if the code text is weird. I just want the program to clear the text in the textBox after they guess.

UPDATE: Added suggested information. Now it does everything it is supposed to do. Except it pops up a windows saying "  was found in the target word". This happens if guessLetter == null || guessLetter == correct || guessLetter == false.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string guessLetter = textBox1.Text;
        //textBox1.ReadOnly = true;


        if (targetWord == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please start a new game.");
            textBox1.Text = ("");

        }

        else
        {
            if (targetWord.Contains(guessLetter))
            {


                MessageBox.Show(guessLetter + " was found in the word");
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(guessLetter + " was not found in the word");
                incorrectGuessCtr++;
                textBox3.Text = incorrectGuessCtr.ToString();
            }
            textBox1.Text = ("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Basics. textBox1.Text = String.Empty;

Comment: Kind of curious but how does it this work if they type more than one letter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear all data / string in a TextBox in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479049/how-to-clear-all-data-string-in-a-textbox-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Add a tag, is this `Winforms` or `WPF`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't only check if the `targetWord` is null, but also the `guessLetter`. You'd better use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` too, since it also checks if the string is empty:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetWord) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(guessLetter))
{
    ...
}
```

I guess you should also check if there is exactly one letter entered. That would mean this additional check:

```
if (guessLetter.Length == 1)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You fixed the problem I was having, now I'll fix the next one. I also updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

You will enter this event when you write code that changes Text property in textbox. I mean this.

```
  textBox3.Text = incorrectGuessCtr.ToString();
```

Put something in function arguments or set some flags so that you can identify whether the event is called from user input or your clearing the text.
Just check how many times this function is called when user press backspace. You will get the idea.